# Windows service DLL and WepApp API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dll, windows-services

we have done one windows service to access serial port, from this we are communicating with to a hardware by a DLL using web app API.

i am creating instances of the DLL in **ApiController** problem is in web App for every Http request my DLL is making new instance(freshly starting).

how to overcome this..? i want to use same instance of the DLL throughout the application once it got instantiated.

Thanks
Vinod

Comment: you can use singleton pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A controller is created per request, and if you want a singleton of the class ("DLL" as you are referring) then you need to perform some [dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection) for the controller.

Comment: Thank you @Mike_G for your reply,i worked on your answer, unfortunately i din't find any solution which will do dependency injection of a DLL for Web API, kindly provide more inputs for this

Comment: @vinodswamy You need clarify what you mean by "DLL".   In your original question you mention DLL, but describe the behavior of  a class. DLL is the actual output file the project is compiled to.  A class is defined within a DLL file.

Comment: We have a bio metric thermal printer, to make it  work we made a DLL it is by compiling three classes one for usb connection , one for bio metric operation and another one for printer operation. this DLL works normally as i using like referencing from bin folder, i am creating the instance of these three class but every http request new instance are creating.